# Lazily initialize a Java map in a thread safe manner

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, double-checked-locking

I need to lazily initialize a map and its contents. I have the below code till now:

```
class SomeClass {
    private Map<String, String> someMap = null;

    public String getValue(String key) {
        if (someMap == null) {
            synchronized(someMap) {
                someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // initialize the map contents by loading some data from the database.
                // possible for the map to be empty after this.
            }
        }
        return someMap.get(key);  // the key might not exist even after initialization
    }
}
```

This is obviously not thread-safe as if one thread comes when `someMap` is null, goes on to initialize the field to `new HashMap` and while its still loading the data in the map, another thread does a `getValue` and doesn't get the data when one might have existed.

How can I make sure that the data is loaded in the map only once when the first `getValue` call happens.

Please note that it's possible that the the `key` won't exist in the map after all the initialization. Also, it's possible that the map is simply empty after all the initialization.

Comment: moreover you will receive NullPointerException on the line `synchronized(someMap)` since `someMap` is `null`

Comment: In this thread, people who don't realize how difficult concurrent is.

Comment: @JohnVint pun intended?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Double Check Locking**

Double check locking requires several steps all to be completed in order to work properly, you are missing two of them.

First you will need to make `someMap` into a `volatile` variable. This is so that other threads will see changes made to it when they are made but after the changes are complete.

```
private volatile Map<String, String> someMap = null;
```

You also need a second check for `null` inside the `synchronized` block to make sure that another thread hasn't initialized it for you while you were waiting to enter the synchronized area.

```
    if (someMap == null) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (someMap == null) {
```

**Do not assign until ready for use**

In your generation of the map construct it in a temp variable then assign it at the end.

```
                Map<String, String> tmpMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // initialize the map contents by loading some data from the database.
                // possible for the map to be empty after this.
                someMap = tmpMap;
            }
        }
    }
    return someMap.get(key);
```

To explain why the temporary map is required. As soon as you complete the line `someMap = new HashMap...` then `someMap` is no longer null. That means other calls to `get` will see it and never try to enter the `synchronized` block. They will then try to get from the map without waiting for the database calls to complete.

By making sure the assignment to `someMap` is the last step within the synchronized block that prevents this from happening.

**unmodifiableMap**

As discussed in the comments, for safety it would also be best to save the results in an `unmodifiableMap` as future modifications would not be thread safe. This is not strictly required for a private variable that is never exposed, but it's still safer for the future as it stops people coming in later and changing the code without realizing.

```
            someMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpMap);
```

**Why not use ConcurrentMap?**

`ConcurrentMap` makes individual actions (i.e. `putIfAbsent`) thread-safe but it does not meet the fundamental requirement here of waiting until the map is fully populated with data before allowing reads from it.

Additionally in this case the Map after the lazy initialization is not being modified again. The `ConcurrentMap` would add synchronization overhead to operations that in this specific use case do not need to be synchronized.

**Why synchronize on *this*?**

There is no reason. :) It was just the simplest way to present a valid answer to this question.

It would certainly be better practice to synchronize on a private internal object. You have improved encapsulation traded off for marginally increased memory usage and object creation times. The main risk with synchronizing on `this` is that it allows other programmers to access your lock object and potentially try synchronizing on it themselves. This then causes un-needed contention between their updates and yours, so an internal lock object is safer.

In reality though a separate lock object is overkill in many cases. It's a judgement call based on the complexity of your class and how widely is is used against the simplicity of just locking on `this`. If in doubt you should probably use an internal lock object and take the safest route.

In the class:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

In the method:

```
synchronized(lock) {
```

As for `java.util.concurrent.locks` objects, they don't add anything useful in this case (although in other cases they are very useful). We always want to wait until the data is available so the standard synchronized block gives us exactly the behavior we need.

Comment: That's the most common idiom. Recommended. I would use Guava's immutable map if the data is not subject to change.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta If guava is not available `Collections.unmodifiableMap` is the most common I have seen.

Comment: @JohnVint Actually in this case if the map is private and the values never change [it doesn't matter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html).

Comment: Huh?  I am saying, if Guava is not available on the classpath, the best alternative is `Collections.unmodifiableMap`.  It serves the same purpose as the ImmutableMap in terms of not allowing the contents to change.

Comment: I would hasten to add that the double check *only works* because the second one happens inside the synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

I think TimB explained most of the options very well, but I think the quickest and most obvious answer would be to create it when the class instance is instantiated.

```
class SomeClass {
    private final Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return someMap.get(key);  // the key might not exist even after initialization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you want to lazy initialize your map is because the generation of values is resource intensive. Generally you can differentiate between two usecases

1. Generation/storage of each value is equally expensive
2. Generation of values is expensive but if you generate one, generating the rest is not that expensive anymore (for example you need to query a database)

The [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a solution for both. Use a [Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) to generate values on the fly or a [CacheLoader](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) + `loadAll` to bulk generate values. Since the initialization of an empty Cache is virtually free there is no need to use the [double check idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking): simply assign the Cache instance to a `private final` field.

Comment: As I understand a cache from the first glance, this helps with adding items to the cache, but not creating the cache lazily in the first place.

Comment: @Silly Freak The cache is created lazy as you invoke [get](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html)

Comment: I'm talking about `Cache c = null; c.get(key);` throwing a NPE. The OP was asking about safely creating the Cache/Map, not inserting into it.

Comment: He asked about lazy initialization of the map. Since creating an empty cache/map is essentially free there is no reason to not always initialize the field. This way `c.get(key)` will never throw a NPE but the contents will be initialized lazy.

Comment: It may well be that it's cheap, but you don't answer the question the OP asked. The OP checks whether the data is loaded by checking for `null`, and the initialized map may well be empty. By creating an empty map in advance, pre- and post-initialization can't be distinguished. Moreover, the OP is talking about atomically initializing the whole map, not loading individual entries on demand. Likewise, he/she doesn't seem to need additional features like capacity or expiry of entries.

Comment: I actually like the idea but it might not fit the use case. If the data for the given key can be lazily loaded, then a cache is a great fit. However, if the whole map must be lazily loaded, then I am not sure this will work in the same easy way as other solutions.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta you are right and that's what [CacheLoader.loadAll](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) is for. Since in most usecases generating values scales linearly i restrictet my answer to the common case :)

Comment: @ooxi Your answer would benefit from some of this comment information being included in it. Currently the answer itself is a little terse.